# Spark Scala [for loop embedded with if-else] how can I not receive duplicate array

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to count some certain words in array RDD level. It almost halfway done. However, the result shows not the exactly same that I'm looking for.

I'm dealing with wine review comment like

```
var aa = dataset.map(c => c(2))
```

> `Array[String] = Array("This tremendous 100% varietal wine hails from Oakville and was aged over three years in oak. Juicy red-cherry fruit and a compelling hint of caramel greet the palate, "Ripe aromas of fig, "Mac Watson honors the memory of a wine once made by his mother in this tremendously delicious, "This spent 20 months in 30% new French oak, "This is the top wine from La Bégude, "Deep,`

I'm trying to count the number of certain words in a list

```
var positive_list= List( "tremendously","delicious")
var sum=0

var rr=aa.map(column =>
                 for (i <- positive_list) yield { 
                    if(column.contains(i)){
                      sum=sum+1
                      (column,sum)
                    } else {
                      (column,0)
                    }
                 })

rr.take(50)
```

Result:

> `Array(List(("This tremendous 100% varietal wine hails from Oakville and was aged over three years in oak. Juicy red-cherry fruit and a compelling hint of caramel greet the palate,0), ("This tremendous 100% varietal wine hails from Oakville and was aged over three years in oak. Juicy red-cherry fruit and a compelling hint of caramel greet the palate,0)), List(("Ripe aromas of fig,0), ("Ripe aromas of fig,0)), List(("Mac Watson honors the memory of a wine once made by his mother in this tremendously delicious,1), ("Mac Watson honors the memory of a wine once made by his mother in this tremendously delicious,2))`

As you can see. There are some duplicate list that I don't really need.
I know that is because  [yield] will return result each time in a loop, but I can't remove it ,otherwise I will get none in the list.

Is there any idea I can do?

Comment: Why do it this way with Spark?

Comment: Simple fix you can just use and distinct to get rid of duplicates. Correct fix you get rid of the vars and do it in a more Scala way.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each element in `positive_list` you are creating a record with the for loop. I assume that you want to map your review to the number of positive words it contains (so just one record per review). You can do it by using `count` on `positive_list`:

```
var rr=aa.map(column => column -> positive_list.count(column.contains))
```